# issue with opera and border radius selection arrow showing outside when animated

Tags: select, border, opera, geometry

view the example here:  http://qwee.net

the problem is only on safari

when viewing the page on safari the link arrow pops up a ways outside the spinning circle.
On firefox the select cursor changes exactly on the border.

I assume the issue is something with safari allowing the area outside the border radius to be selected... not sure

my code looks something like this:

```
@keyframes spincounterclockwise {
0%   {transform: rotate(360deg); -o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
100% {transform: rotate(0deg); -o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
}

#circle {
width: 350px;
height: 350px;
animation: spincounterclockwise 2s linear 0s infinite normal;
background: black;
border-radius: 175px 175px 175px 175px;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: -175px;
margin-top: -175px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
position: fixed;
}

<a href="link location"><div id="circle"></div></a>
```

Comment: I found this article and I am working on it as a complex javascript solution... If anyone knows of an easier work-around please let me know!

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/22/hover-and-click-trigger-circular-elements/

Answer (score 0):

I would think about this again!

I don't think this works in most used browsers, f.e. Opera12.9 & IE 10.0 doesn't rotate.
As you said, sometimes the cursor doesn't change correct.

Have you thought about implementing the sign as css3 styled rectancles with border radius?
(I can not see if you have used an image or something else to display it)

Or could you at least provide some more code, because there is some missing in your question for sure!

Comment: you can view my current development example here:
http://nathangoodfellow.us/qwee.net
I have fixed the code so that IE users get an alternative flash animation
the sign is implement as a css styled rectangle with a border radius
it appears that when a div is given a border radius in webkit that the div is still selectable OUTSIDE the border-radius.
Let me know what additional code is needed.
I only need this working on webkit, firefox and opera, the animations are working for me on my opera here is my version info:
Version  12.15 Build  1748 Platform  Win32 System  Windows 7

Comment: I'll have a look, I am using the same built of opera but on Windows 8